# send variable latitude longitude to google map direction?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, uri

i want to passing variable latitude longitude to google map direction?
can help me see the error or have a new solution?
this is my java code :

```
public void onClickShowMap(View v) {
      String latitude = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude)).getText().toString();
      String longitude = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude)).getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,          
    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr="+latitude+","+longitude));
    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: I do recommend you to use my library which creates the query for you and parses the input data which can be easily used: https://github.com/perezdidac/google-directions-api

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=" + lat
                    + "," + lon + "&daddr=" + lattitude + ","
                    +longitude));
    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps",
            "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
    ((Activity) this).startActivity(intent);